# Infinispan server giving "Unauthorized Action" while changing anything from web console

Tags: keycloak, kubernetes-helm, infinispan

[Infinispan web console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tL4te.png)
I am getting Unauthorized action error on changing anything in the infinispan server. E.g. when turning off cluster rebalancing, I am getting error

```
 Unexpected error when rebalancing disabled. "Unauthorized action."
```

I have installed infinispan server using helm chart and following values.yaml

```
deploy:
  replicas: 2
  container:
    env:
    storage:
      size: 1Gi
      storageClassName: "infinispan-storage"
      # [USER] Set `ephemeral: true` to delete all persisted data when clusters shut down or restart.
      ephemeral: true
    resources:
      # [USER] Specify the CPU limit and the memory limit for each pod.
      limits:
        cpu: 500m
        memory: 512Mi
      # [USER] Specify the maximum CPU requests and the maximum memory requests for each pod.
      requests:
        cpu: 500m
        memory: 512Mi
```

For logging into the server, first I have tried with developer (user) whose corresponding secrets got from automatically generated and secondly, I have also created admin user. But still getting unauthorized action.

Answer (score 0):

we've hit this issue as well and it seems to be related to using a reverse proxy in front using SSL. Disabled SSL on the routes and it's now working fine under HTTP.

I'll let you know if we find a solution to reinstate it.

Comment: Thanks, FYI I was using SSL in front of reverse proxy (nginx-ingress) and terminating the encryption at reverse proxy only.

Comment: Yeah, I started a chat in there Zulip to figure it out, seems to require a bit extra work setting up SSL certs all the way through (not just EDGE) - I just haven't had time to investigate further.